# source data changed when using reduce in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, es6-promise, reduce

My code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      services: [],
      mydata: [
        {id: 1, count: 102, price: 0.1},
        {id: 1, count: 0, price: 0.09},
        {id: 2, count: 20, price: 0.5},
      ]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.start();
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.services = this.mydata.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        let item = acc.find((obj) => obj.id == curr.id);
        if (item) {
          item.count += curr.count;
          item.price = item.price > curr.price ? curr.price : item.price;
        } else {
          acc.push(curr);
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
    },
  },
};
```

I want merge the `mydata` array and save into a `services` variable. I want that the `count`s to be sum and the lower `price` to be selected for the new object. (I used `reduce` for doing this)

My expected `services`:

```
[
        {id: 1, count: 102, price: 0.09},
        {id: 2, count: 20, price: 0.5},
]
```

It's works but the source data (which is `mydata`) manipulated and converted to this: (the first object's `price` manipulated and converted to 0.09 which it was 0.1 before)

```
[
        {id: 1, count: 102, price: 0.09},
        {id: 1, count: 0, price: 0.09},
        {id: 2, count: 20, price: 0.5}
]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Remove the observable attached to `mydata`: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)).reduce...`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

You're actually modyfying `mydata`.

It happens when you find object in the array:

```js
let item = acc.find((obj) => obj.id == curr.id);
```

and then modify it

```js
item.count += curr.count;
item.price = item.price > curr.price ? curr.price : item.price;
```

### Why it happens?

In JavaScript we have two types od data types.

- Primitive types (`Boolean`, `String`, `Number`, `null`, `undefined`) and they are passed **by value**.
- `Array`, `Function` and `Object` which are are passed **by reference**

In your case you're finding some object in the array and then modify its properties which means you're operating on the reference.

### How to do it?

1. If you have array of primitive types you can make shallow copy using for example spread operator:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[...arr].reduce()
```

2. If you have array of complex types you need to write custom fuction or use some library which implements it for you like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)).reduce... and it worked. Does it have an equivalent in Lodash?

Comment: @FredII Have in mind that using `JSON.parse` method will lose information about some data. If your objects contain `undefined`, `NaN`, `Infinity` or functions all of them will be replaced with `null`. Lodash has `_.cloneDeep` function